# Why do i get an error when trying to disable shadow casting on GPU instanced object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Errors i get
Argument 4: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<UnityEngine.Matrix4x4>' to 'UnityEngine.Matrix4x4[]'
Argument 5: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Rendering.ShadowCastingMode' to 'int'

I am a complete beginner so i don't really know what these errors mean or how to fix them.
[THE CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jlq2M.png)

I'm trying to GPU Instance a bunch of grass but i don't want the grass to cast shadows. I try to disable shadow casting but i get errors. I'm very new to C# and Unity so if you can explain how to fix in a way beginner can understand I would appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: it suggests you got the parameters wrong.  You're sending an array when it wants an int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 issues here.

The [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.DrawMeshInstanced.html) defines 2 signatures for the function you're using.

The 1st one is :

```
public static void DrawMeshInstanced(Mesh mesh, int submeshIndex, Material material, Matrix4x4[] matrices, int count = matrices.Length, MaterialPropertyBlock properties = null, Rendering.ShadowCastingMode castShadows = ShadowCastingMode.On, bool receiveShadows = true, int layer = 0, Camera camera = null, Rendering.LightProbeUsage lightProbeUsage = LightProbeUsage.BlendProbes, LightProbeProxyVolume lightProbeProxyVolume = null);
```

The 2nde one is :

```
public static void DrawMeshInstanced(Mesh mesh, int submeshIndex, Material material, List<Matrix4x4> matrices, MaterialPropertyBlock properties = null, Rendering.ShadowCastingMode castShadows = ShadowCastingMode.On, bool receiveShadows = true, int layer = 0, Camera camera = null, Rendering.LightProbeUsage lightProbeUsage = LightProbeUsage.BlendProbes, LightProbeProxyVolume lightProbeProxyVolume = null);
```

We'll focus on the 5-6 first parameters of each function to ease the readability :

```
Mesh mesh, int submeshIndex, Material material, Matrix4x4[] matrices, int count = matrices.Length,

Mesh mesh, int submeshIndex, Material material, List<Matrix4x4> matrices, MaterialPropertyBlock properties = null, Rendering.ShadowCastingMode castShadows
```

Obviously, you want to use the 2nd one, but Unity understands the 1st one instead. Why is that ? Because, the 5th parameters you gave is `shadowCasting` whose the initialization value is [OFF](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.ShadowCastingMode.html). Off, is a value from an `enumeration`. Its underlying type is an int. This is the root cause of your 2 error messages.

Furthermore, the function you want to use is NOT as you use it. Take a close look to the 5th parameter, its type is of `MaterialPropertyBlock` (with a default value of null). You're passing to the function the next parameter to this one.

Conclusion :
Rewrite your call as such :
`Graphics.DrawMeshInstanced(mesh, i, material[i], Batch, null, shadowCasting);`